# Error while fetch data from db

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, sql, collection-filtering, fatal-error

I am Trying to fetch and filter data from database

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('some/some')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter(something);
```

but it give me an error

Fatal error: Call to undefined method `My_Comment_Model_Mysql4_Comment_Collection::addAttributeToFilter()` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\sahara\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\comment\comment.phtml` on line 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your model is `not an  Eav Model`  and it is a `simple flat table`Model .So You cannot used `addAttributeToFilter()` function for filter the collection.

You can use `addFieldToFilter()` in that  case

Comment: good catch amit